# Is there a way to update publication metadata dynamically while publishing page/component?

Tags: publishing, dd4t, 2013-sp1, binary, metadata

We are using Tridion 2013sp1. And DD4T at content delivery. Our binaries are published to cdn server. Each publication target will publish binaries to different cdn server. Hence, we are unable to resolve image paths automatically for different environments in our web application using DD4T as image path is resolved with path mentioned in publication metadata "image path".

Now, I'm looking for a way to change publication metadata dynamically while publishing from Tridion according to publication target.

Answer (score 2):

You may also want to consider modifying the publish path using a Custom Renderer.

A Custom Renderer can be used to manipulate the output produced by the template process.

More information can be found in the online doc's here:
http://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL%20Tridion%20full%20documentation-v1/GUID-63F2D210-B270-42D6-939E-8D33D927C19C

Comment: Hi Jonathan, thanks for highlighting about custom renderer. I will check this option.

Answer (score 1):

There's 2 ways that I see you can resolve this issue:

*From the CMS when publishing:*

- Use Hiren's approach and add a TBB (that fixes the binary paths) in the existing **Dynamic Component** and **Dynamic Page** templates.

*From the WebApplication when resolving the images:*

- Implement your own BinaryDistributionModule,check the dd4t implementation here: https://github.com/dd4t/DD4T.MVC/blob/develop/source/DD4T.Web/Binaries/BinaryDistributionModule.cs

Answer (score 0):

Instead of updating the publication metadata, you can consider below approach.

> 1. Create a configuration component with key value pair of Target &
>      corresponding CDN url.
> 2. Create TBB that will read above configuration and override the existing CDN url.
> 3. Include this new TBB in your template for publishing.